# Retrieve sent email id on send

Tags: office-js

I'm developing an Office add-in that saves information related to the email (associated by the emai's itemId) to an external database.

I would like to perform a similar operation before or immediately when the email is sent, but the itemId does not exist on an email that is still being composed.

Is there an API for receiving a notification once the email is sent? The [on send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic) feature could possibly be exploited for this purpose, but I'd prefer an official way if it exists.

If not, is there another API that might solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the itemId, you will have to save the item. 
The response of [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#saveasyncoptions-callback) contains the itemId.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
  function callback(result) {
    if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      itemId = result.value;
    }
  }
);
```

Note:

1. You can use [getItemIdAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getitemidasyncoptions-callback) preview API, but I recommend **not** to use preview APIs in your production environment.
2. Mac Outlook does not support saving a meeting. If you are targeting only emails saveAsync should work, but for meetings follow [work around](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4505745/cannot-save-meeting-as-draft-in-outlook-for-mac-using-office-js-api)

**Edit:**

No, there is no other way (apart from on-send feature) to get contents from the email, immediately when the email is sent.
You will have to get the itemId and then get the email content synced from exchange to your external database. The work around for Mac could be the solution for your problem.